# cannot find file with ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I have a default package called `com.voja.springtest` and another one called `com.voja.springtest.beans` where I have an `beans.xml` file.

I can get it like so using `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` :

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("C:/Users/Voja/Desktop/_/vj/springtest/src/main/java/com/voja/springtest/beans/beans.xml");
```

But `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` can't find it like so (and it should per the tutorial I am doing):

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/voja/springtest/beans/beans.xml");
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use wrong parh , in your case it should be like :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:beans.xml");
```

> 4.7.2.2 The classpath*: prefix
>
> When constructing an XML-based application context, a location string
>   may use the special classpath*: prefix:
>
> ApplicationContext ctx =
>       new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:conf/appContext.xml"); This
>   special prefix specifies that all classpath resources that match the
>   given name must be obtained (internally, this essentially happens via
>   a ClassLoader.getResources(...) call), and then merged to form the
>   final application context definition.

[The Classpath*: portability classpath*: prefix](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-classpath-wildcards)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to find it but now it complains that it cannot find the actual bean, and with FileSystem I had no problem whatsoever. Any idea why classpath can find the xml file but not the bean defined within it? Once again, it worked with FileSystem.

Comment: move this file beans.xml into 'C:/Users/Voja/Desktop/_/vj/springtest/src/main/resources'. resources - it's right place for config

Answer (score 0):

FileSystemXmlApplicationContext picks the XML file from absolute path by appending keyword "file" and also can fetch from classpath by appending keyword "classpath". 
You can access the file as below

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-app.xml");
```